# What would be an example of when it would be beneficial or circumstantially required to include 2 highly correlated terms in a model?

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, inference, experiment-design, multicollinearity

What would be an example of a situation where very correlated terms must be included? When is this more beneficial as opposed to selecting 1 of the terms?

Comment: In what context? What kind of model are you considering?

Comment: any situation in which the contrast of those variables is important. E.g. intake of omega fatty acids correlate, but for many relationships (e.g. heart disease) the *difference* or *ratio* of the omega fatty acids (omega 3 versus 6) is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the variables are true drivers you must include them. For instance, [VIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIX) and [SPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P_500_Index) indices are highly correlated, to the tune of -0.7 or even -0.9. So, it's tempting to drop one of them from the model, and in fact you'd hear people saying you should.

However, consider an equity [option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_(finance)), its price depends on both the price and volatility among other parameters. VIX and SPX indices represent the volatility (expectations) and price of equities on the market. Hence, if you deal with products that are related to equity options, I could argue that you certainly should *try* including both drivers into the model. This is because although the indices are highly negatively correlated sometime they move together, and given high sensitivity of option prices to both drivers you may get interesting results.

For instance, [call option price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_(finance)#Long_call) increases when the underlying equity price increases. The equity prices are correlated with the SPX index. So, when the SPX jumps call option prices should be pushed up, but in this case VIX is usually going down, which pulls the price down. So, the effects cancel each other to some degree. However, in less frequent cases when VIX goes together with PSX up, both price and volatility moves will be pushing call option price up. If you only have VIX or SPX in the model, you'll be completely missing this dynamic.